# Binding content from other files in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I planning to bind label from two files or more, because I place the label and the cs file in separate way. For example:

SettingServicesPhone.xaml

```
<Label x:Name="sipLoginStatus"
  Width="106"
  Height="27"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  VerticalAlignment="Top"
  Content="{Binding SipLoginStatusContent}"
  FontSize="13" />
```

For the SettingServicePhone.xaml.cs I declared `public String sipLoginStatusContent;`

And I use Settings.xaml and Setting.xaml.cs as a container of all functions.
I've declared `public static SettingsServicesPhone setCall = new SettingsServicesPhone();` on `Setting.xaml.cs`. And also write `get set`.

```
public String SipLoginStatusContent
{
    get { return setCall.sipLoginStatusContent; }
    set
    {
        if (setCall.sipLoginStatusContent != value)
        {
            setCall.sipLoginStatusContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SipLoginStatusContent");  // To notify when the property is changed
        }
    }
}
```

And here the example of onclick button that I stated on Settings.xaml.cs

```
public void applyBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   SipLoginStatusContent = "Logging In";
}
```

It's work fine if I included them in one file. But seems like it doesn't running if I make it separate. Am I doing it wrong way? Thank you.

Comment: I can run any other function from outside, but not with binding the item.

Comment: What do you mean with 'it doesn't running'? What do you expect it to do, and what actually happens? Note that bindings are resolved against a view's `DataContext`, and a common pattern (MVVM) is to use 'view-model' objects for that. In this case, both views could use the same view-model object as their data context, so a change in one view will automatically be reflected in the other view.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I expect the label change to something like 'Logged in', but it doesn't work. Sadly I didn't use MVVM on this project, I am new on WPF and C#.

Comment: To be clear: you expect the label in your `SettingServicesPhone` view to change, when you click a button in your `Settings` view? I don't know how you're creating those views, but you probably have two `SettingServicesPhone` *instances* - a visible one, and an invisible one that's referenced by that `setCall` field. `setCall` should reference the already existing, visible instance instead (and you probably shouldn't use `static` if you don't understand the difference between a class and an instance yet).

Comment: Yes, that what I mean. I created it by `Settings` as container by `ContentControl` and SettingServicesPhone as it content. I've change deleted the static, and nothing change.

Comment: I didn't say that removing `static` would solve it, I said that you likely have two different `SettingServicesPhone` objects - you're modifying a different object than the one you're displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DataContext` of the window where the `Label` is defined to an instance of the class where the `SipLoginStatusContent` property is defined:

```
public partial class Settings : Window
{
    public static SettingsServicesPhone setCall = new SettingsServicesPhone();

    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this; //<--
    }

    public String SipLoginStatusContent
    {
        get { return setCall.sipLoginStatusContent; }
        set
        {
            if (setCall.sipLoginStatusContent != value)
            {
                setCall.sipLoginStatusContent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SipLoginStatusContent");  // To notify when the property is changed
            }
        }
    }

    public void applyBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SipLoginStatusContent = "Logging In";
    }
}
```